# Не работает кнопки на инлайн клавиатуре в библиотеке telebot

Tags: telebot

```
import telebot
import config

 
from telebot import types
 


bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.TOKEN)


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def welcome(message):
    #sti = open('static/welcome.webp', 'rb')
    #bot.send_sticker(message.chat.id, sti)
 
    # keyboard
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    item1 = types.KeyboardButton("Записаться на приём")
    item2 = types.KeyboardButton("посмотреть запись")
    item3 = types.KeyboardButton("Отрыть адрес в 2гис")
 
    markup.add(item1, item2, item3)
 
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Ассаляму алейкум, {0.first_name}!\nЯ - <b>{1.first_name}</b>, который осуществляет ремонт впрыска, электрик. Адрес улица джумалиева 13 А город Алматы. Телефон +77772398509. В этом боте вы можете занять очередь на прием онлайн и рассказать что вас беспокоит в автомобиле.".format(message.from_user, bot.get_me()),
        parse_mode='html', reply_markup=markup)




@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def zapis(message):
    if message.chat.type == 'private':
        if message.text == 'посмотреть запись':
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'за какой день?')
        elif message.text == 'Записаться на приём':
 
            markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
            item1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Понедельник", callback_data='PN')
            item2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Вторник", callback_data='VT')
            item3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Среда", callback_data='SR')
            item4 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Четверг", callback_data='CHT')
            item5 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Пятница", callback_data='PT')
            item6 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Суббота", callback_data='SB')
            item7 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Воскресенье", callback_data='VS')
            item8 = types.InlineKeyboardButton ("Назад", callback_data = 'nazad')
            
 
            markup.add(item1, item2, item3, item4, item5, item6, item7, item8)
 
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Выберите день', reply_markup=markup)
        elif message.text == 'Отрыть адрес в 2гис' :
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'нажмите на ссылку, чтобы посмотреть адрес в 2гис https://go.2gis.com/691dk')
        else:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Я не знаю что ответить ')
 
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_inline(call):
    try:
        if call.message:
            if call.data == 'PN':
                
                markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
                item1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("9:00", callback_data='9')
                item2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("10:00", callback_data='10')
                item3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("11:00", callback_data='11')
                item4 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("12:00", callback_data='12')
                item5 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("13:00", callback_data='13')
                item6 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("14:00", callback_data='14')
                item7 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("15:00", callback_data='15')
                item8 = types.InlineKeyboardButton ("Назад", callback_data = 'nazad')
                
     
                markup.add(item1, item2, item3, item4, item5, item6, item7, item8)
     
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Вы записаны', reply_markup=markup)
                bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Вот и отличненько ')
            elif call.data == 'VT':
                bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Бывает ')
 
            # remove inline buttons
            bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id, text=" Как дела?",
                reply_markup=None)
 
            # show alert
            bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query_id=call.id, show_alert=False,
                text="ЭТО ТЕСТОВОЕ УВЕДОМЛЕНИЕ!!11")
 
    except Exception as e:
        print(repr(e))
 
# RUN
bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Исправленный код:

```
import telebot
import config
 
from telebot import types
 


bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.TOKEN)


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def welcome(message):
    #sti = open('static/welcome.webp', 'rb')
    #bot.send_sticker(message.chat.id, sti)
 
    # keyboard
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    item1 = types.KeyboardButton("Записаться на приём")
    item2 = types.KeyboardButton("посмотреть запись")
    item3 = types.KeyboardButton("Отрыть адрес в 2гис")
 
    markup.add(item1, item2, item3)
 
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Ассаляму алейкум, {0.first_name}!\nЯ - <b>{1.first_name}</b>, который осуществляет ремонт впрыска, электрик. Адрес улица ######## ## А город #####. Телефон ############. В этом боте вы можете занять очередь на прием онлайн и рассказать что вас беспокоит в автомобиле.".format(message.from_user, bot.get_me()),
        parse_mode='html', reply_markup=markup)




@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def zapis(message):
    if message.chat.type == 'private':
        if message.text == 'посмотреть запись':
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'за какой день?')
        elif message.text == 'Записаться на приём':
 
            markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
            item1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Понедельник", callback_data='PN')
            item2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Вторник", callback_data='VT')
            item3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Среда", callback_data='SR')
            item4 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Четверг", callback_data='CHT')
            item5 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Пятница", callback_data='PT')
            item6 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Суббота", callback_data='SB')
            item7 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Воскресенье", callback_data='VS')
            item8 = types.InlineKeyboardButton ("Назад", callback_data = 'nazad')
            
 
            markup.add(item1, item2, item3, item4, item5, item6, item7, item8)
 
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Выберите день', reply_markup=markup)
        elif message.text == 'Отрыть адрес в 2гис' :
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'нажмите на ссылку, чтобы посмотреть адрес в 2гис https://go.2gis.com/691dk')
        else:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Я не знаю что ответить ')
 
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_inline(call):
    try:
        if call.message:
            if call.data == 'PN':
                
                markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
                item1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("9:00", callback_data='9')
                item2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("10:00", callback_data='10')
                item3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("11:00", callback_data='11')
                item4 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("12:00", callback_data='12')
                item5 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("13:00", callback_data='13')
                item6 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("14:00", callback_data='14')
                item7 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("15:00", callback_data='15')
                item8 = types.InlineKeyboardButton ("Назад", callback_data = 'nazad')
                
     
                markup.add(item1, item2, item3, item4, item5, item6, item7, item8)
     
                bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Вы записаны', reply_markup=markup)
                bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Вот и отличненько ')
            elif call.data == 'VT':
                bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Бывает ')
 
            # remove inline buttons
            bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id, text=" Как дела?",
                reply_markup=None)
 
            # show alert
            bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query_id=call.id, show_alert=False,
                text="ЭТО ТЕСТОВОЕ УВЕДОМЛЕНИЕ!!11")
 
    except Exception as e:
        print(repr(e))
 
# RUN
bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Ошибка заключалась в том что в строке

```
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Вы записаны', reply_markup=markup)
```

не находило переменной message, так как в функцию было передано call, нужно было исправить на

```
bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Вы записаны', reply_markup=markup)
```